# How can I add specific escape characters to xmlserializer?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a method that serializes an object to xml and returns the string:

```
public static string SerializeType<T>(T item)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        using (var stringWriter = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, item);
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

However, it is not removing all the reserved characters from strings in objects I pass in. Microsoft lists the [Reserved Characters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145315%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) as <>&% but when I input an item with a "abc&cd%d" string field, it spits out "a &lt ;ab&gt ;bc&amp ;cd%d" without out the spaces preceding the semicolons. % is not being escaped. How can I add the correct escape sequence for percent? The % causes an error when I send it to a client's app.  The escaping listed on that page fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` isn't really a reserved character in XML. The documentation you've referred to is for SQL server, and there's a small note under the table:

> The Notification Services XML vocabulary reserves the percent sign (%) for denoting parameters.

But you shouldn't expect `XmlSerializer` (or any other general-purpose XML library) to escape `%` for you. Unless you're *using* "Notification Services XML" I wouldn't expect this to be a problem.

Comment: I added a little more info on why I need to add this character. I would guess the client's app should be making this change/removing this flaw but this ultimately falls onto me. This answer doesn't really answer my question. How would you recommend handling this if not in the serializer?

Comment: @Bishop: What *is* the client's app? And why can't they get that fixed? You could always just manually replace `%` in the string afterwards, if you really have to - but you should at least let the client know that they're rejecting perfectly good XML.

Comment: It is a java servlet. Letting them know was a given. They have just proven to be slow making changes, and already have a pretty substantial backlog. Thanks for the help Jon.